# Poisson Deviance - How to Estimate the Optimal Nodes for a Decision Tree

Tags: poisson-distribution, cart, loss-functions, boosting, deviance

The following is the formulation for how the GBM package in R calculates the loss function and terminal node estimates for gradient boosting with decision trees. My question is generally how are the optimal node estimates determined analyticalally and specifically as an example, for the Poisson deviance?
[image]

Where do these terminal node estimates come from - knowing that these are the best prediction to minimize the loss?

Comment: Why close votes? I am asking a statistical question if the Log Lik are equivalent and how to determine the loss minimizing estimate.

Comment: @B_Miner I agree that this is completely on topic.  I think the community would prefer that you do not post an image of the mathematics though, the site supports latex inline.  We have hard of vision users that use screen readers to participate in the site.

Comment: I reworked it to remove the main R components and settle on the main question. My latex skills are such that I would still be typing this out, but I get the concern and will try and revisit.